# gunicorn systemd startup not working with django inside a vagrant box

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, chef-infra, gunicorn

I translated [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial into a chef recipe. And so far everything apart from starting gunicorn (the right way) seems to be working.

For example when I shut down the machine after the initial setup and provisioning via `vagrant halt` and then start it up again with `vagrant up` - I always get an `502 Bad Gateway` error.
Then I have to ssh into the box and run these commands manualy

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

After that everything is working again.

What I dont understand is when I run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` before I reload the daemon and restart gunicorn - it tells me that gunicorn is running.

Here is my `gunicorn.service` file contents that get written to `/etc/systemd/sytem/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/vagrant_data
ExecStart=/vagrant_data/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/run/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application --reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My projects folder structure is:

```
/home/ubuntu/myproject ls
   manage.py myproject myprojectenv

/home/ubuntu/run ls
   myproject.sock
```

I symlinked the `myproject` folder to `vagrant_data` which is setup to be the  `vm.synced_folder` in my Vagrantfile.

this is all running on a `ubuntu/xenial64` vagrant box.

**UPDATE:**

```
include_recipe 'locale'

include_recipe 'apt'

execute 'install requirements' do
    command 'sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx'
    not_if ('sudo dpkg -l | grep postgresql')
end

bash 'setup database and user' do
    user 'postgres'
    code <<-EOF
        echo "CREATE DATABASE #{node['dbname']};" | psql
        echo "CREATE USER #{node['dbuser']} WITH PASSWORD '#{node['dbpass']}';" | psql
        echo "ALTER ROLE #{node['dbuser']} SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';" | psql
        echo "ALTER ROLE #{node['dbuser']} SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';" | psql
        echo "ALTER ROLE #{node['dbuser']} SET timezone TO 'UTC';" | psql
        echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE #{node['dbname']} TO #{node['dbuser']};" | psql
    EOF
    not_if { `sudo -u postgres psql -tAc \"SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE datname='#{node['dbname']}'\" | wc -l`.chomp == "1" }
end

execute 'install virtualenv' do
    command 'sudo pip3 install virtualenv'
    not_if ('sudo pip3 list | grep virtualenv')
end

link "/home/ubuntu/#{node['projectDir']}" do
  to '/vagrant_data'
  owner 'ubuntu'
  group 'www-data'
end

directory '/home/ubuntu/run' do
  owner 'ubuntu'
  group 'www-data'
  action :create
end

bash 'configure and install django' do
    code <<-EOF
        cd /home/ubuntu/#{node['projectDir']}
        virtualenv myprojectenv
        source myprojectenv/bin/activate
        pip install django gunicorn psycopg2
        django-admin.py startproject #{node['projectDir']} .
        deactivate
    EOF
    not_if { ::File::exists?("/home/ubuntu/#{node['projectDir']}/#{node['projectDir']}")}
end

###############
# Note : In development set workers to 1 which will reload the code after each request
# in production set it to cores x 2 + 1 ... which would mostly result in 5 workers
##########
template '/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service' do
    source 'gunicorn.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
end

template '/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject' do
    source 'test.erb'
    owner 'www-data'
    group 'www-data'
end

execute 'link to sites-enabled' do
    command 'sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled'
    not_if { ::File.symlink?('/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject')}
end

execute 'remove default host' do
    command 'sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default'
    only_if { ::File.exists?('/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default') }
end

bash 'enable gunicorn' do
    code <<-EOF
        sudo systemctl daemon-reload
        sudo systemctl start gunicorn
        sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
    EOF
    #not_if { ::File.exists?('/home/ubuntu/run/myproject.sock')}
end

execute 'test nginx' do
    command 'sudo nginx -t'
end

execute 'restart nginx' do
    command 'sudo service nginx restart'
end
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?
**UPDATE:**

Still not working - after trying almost everything google had to offer.
Now I switched to a kind of workaround with the `vagrant-triggers` plugin and defined the needed commands for gunicorn in Vagrantfile.

```
config.trigger.after :up do
   run_remote "sudo systemctl daemon-reload"
   run_remote "sudo systemctl restart gunicorn"
end
```

That way I don't have to call `vagrant up --provision` every time I turn on the machine.

But still I would really like to know how to get that thing started the right way.

Comment: I'm wildly guessing that it might have to do with the order things are done. Maybe systemd starts gunicorn first and some directory like /vagrant_data is mounted later? That would create enough chaos.

Comment: You might be right - but as far as I know synced folder mounting happens before provisioning. Also the .socket file is not symlinked it stays outside of the project directory.

Comment: Without seeing your actual recipe code anything we say is pure conjecture. If you want to see an example of deploying a Django app with Chef take a look at https://github.com/poise/application_examples/blob/master/recipes/dpaste.rb

Comment: Okay - I will update my answer with the recipe code.

Comment: Another option I think would be to start gunicorn over a .sh script as seen here [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286997/how-to-run-gunicorn-as-systemd-daemon) - but I am not shure how to do that since there are again many many options and possibilities